# VB.net give module access to only specific class

Tags: vb.net, module, private, public

I have a VB net Class which will use very very large string constants...

I want to define these constants in a Module in a different file as to make the code easier to read and update.

I would like the Module to be Private to everything else except the Class that uses it.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Tony

Comment: You don't need to define a module in order to use multiple code files.  Just use partial classes.  Basically, declare the same class in two different code files and include the `Partial` keyword in the declaration of at least one of them and you're good to go.  The compiler treats the code in all the files as a single class, as though all the code was in one.  That's how the WinForms designer keeps the designer-generated code out of your user code file for a form.

Comment: That said, why even bother with multiple code files at all?  Why not just declare your constants in the same class in the same code file and put them inside a region?  You can then just collapse the region and the constants are hidden from you but immediately accessible if required.

Comment: Thank You! I will check out the Partial method